# Loading Perl Modules from non-standard directories

Tags: perl, perl-module

How to load Perl modules using non-standard directories?

I download the trace module from cpan website and put into non-standard directories(/home/nrama/perl-script). but It doesn't taking my non-standard directories while executing below script. please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Trace module  URL:

https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JV/Debug-Trace-0.05/lib/Debug/Trace.pm

**Error:**

syntax error at shift.pl line 3, near "use Trace."
Execution of shift.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

**Sample script:-**

```
use strict;
use lib ("/home/nrama/perl-script");
use Trace.pm;

func('Nataraj', 'vino', 'mano' );
sub func {
my $name_1 = shift;
my $name_2 = shift;
my $name_3 = shift;
print "say hello to $name_1 $name_2 $name_3\n";
}
```

Note: Using perl, v5.6.0

Comment: When you say _downloaded_, what do you mean? What exactly did you do?

Comment: How to use trace module in my script?

Comment: Off-topic. Typo. The problem has nothing to do with the path. When you `use` a module, you need to use the module name, not the file name. `use Debug::Trace`.

Comment: Can't locate Debug/Trace.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/nrama/perl-script /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.6.0/sun4-solaris /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.6.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.6.0/sun4-solaris /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.6.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at shift.pl line 3.

Comment: I am getting an error used the Debug::Trace

Comment: Offtopic: Perl 5.6.0? Released 22nd March 2000?

Comment: Yes, correct. because of Our application using old Perl version.

Comment: Right now you have a syntax error here: `use Trace.pm;`. You are trying to concatenate barewords. Try `use Trace;` or rather `use Debug::Trace` (you need to preserve the directory structure for the latter).

Comment: I am slightly modified my script even doesn't work also updated my script.

Comment: Can't locate Debug/Trace.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/nra/perl-script /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.6.0/sun4-solaris /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.6.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.6.0/sun4-solaris /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.6.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at shift.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at shift.pl line 4

Comment: The script is called `Debug::Trace`, so the `Trace.pm` file needs to be in a folder called `Debug`, ie: `/home/nra/perl-script/Debug/Trace.pm`. Then with your script in `/home/nra/perl-script` it should work.

Comment: I can execute my script(shift.pl). But doesn't show the trace output.
 my script output --> say hello to Nataraj vino mano

Comment: Please help me on this matter.

Comment: Do you mean that you put the module in your home directory that you show?  Then try `use lib '/home/nrama/perl-script';` then `use Debug::Trace;`

Comment: Where is the script located?  Is it being executed by the *nramamoorthy* user or some other user?  If by another user, does that user have access to where the module is located??

Comment: **I can execute my script(shift.pl).  But doesn't show the trace output.**  Does that mean that it's no longer giving you the "Can't Locate Debug/Trace.pm" error but it's also not giving you the trace output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Trace.pm;
```

is not valid Perl, thus the syntax error. That should be

```
use Debug::Trace;
```

---

Furthermore, it makes no sense to harcode an absolute path in a script. You should remove

```
use lib ("/home/nrama/perl-script");
```

and either set env var `PERL5LIB` to that path in the login script

```
export PERL5LIB="$HOME/perl-script"
```

or replace it with a relative path to the script such as

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

or

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/lib";
```